# Why do Multidimentional Arrays replace the first letter of the first key value?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array that is behaving unexpectedly and I would like to know why this is, and if there is a work around. It seems that if I set something in first key of the array, it will replace the first letter of it when I declare a value in it's second key. 
(I'm not sure how to properly describe the behavior but this code should help somewhat:

```
<?php
//Declare Array with first key and value
    $test['hello'] = "Hello There";

//Echo Value
    echo "HELLO TEST: ". $test['hello'] ;

//Declare Multidimensional Array using the first array key and a new key
    $test['hello']['jerk'] = "JERK!";

//Echo Values
    echo "<br/>HELLO TEST: ". $test['hello'] ;
    echo "<br/>JERK TEST : ". $test['hello']['jerk'];
?>
```

That code outputs as follows:

> HELLO TEST: Hello There
>   HELLO TEST: Jello There
>   JERK TEST : J

I expect to see

> HELLO TEST: Hello There
>   HELLO TEST: Hello There
>   JERK TEST : JERK!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing this :

```
$test['hello'] = "Hello There";
```

You declare that `$test['hello']` contains a string.

Then, doing this :

```
$test['hello']['jerk'] = "JERK!";
```

You declare that `$test['hello']` contains an array ; and no longer a string.

Your `$test['hello']` can only contain one thing.

---

Actually, when you are doing this :

```
$test['hello']['jerk'] = "JERK!";
```

As `$test['hello']` contains a string *(and not an array)*, I think PHP will try to access this entry : `$test['hello'][0]`

With `0` being the `jerk` string converted to an integer.

And `$test['hello'][0]` means **the first character of the string that's in `$test['hello']`**

*See [String access and modification by character](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr) in the manual, about that.*

There, now, you're trying to put a whole string (`"JERK!"`) where there can be only one character -- the first one of the existing string. And that one get overriden by the first character of the string `"JERK!"`.

---

**EDIT a while after :** and here are the full explanations, with commented code :

```
// Assign a string to $test['hello']
$test['hello'] = "Hello There";

//Echo Value
var_dump($test['hello']);

// Try to assign a string to $test['hello']['jerk']
$test['hello']['jerk'] = "JERK!";
// But $test['hello'] is a string, so PHP tries to make a string-access to one character
// see http://fr.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr
// As 'jerk' is a string, it gets converted to an integer ; which is 0
// So, you're really trying to do this, here :
$test['hello'][0] = "JERK!";
// And, as you can only put ONE character where ($test['hello'][0]) there is space for only one ,
// only the first character of "JERK!" is kept.
// Which means that what's actually done is :
$test['hello'][0] = "J";

// Still echo the whole string, with the first character that's been overriden
var_dump($test['hello']);

// Same as before : here, you're only accessing $test['hello'][0]
// (which is the first character of the string -- the one that's been overriden)
var_dump($test['hello']['jerk']);
// Same as this :
var_dump($test['hello'][0]);
```

Comment: Thank you for elaborating this is great, I have to rethink my design however :)

Comment: @Mallow : you're welcome :-) *(I've edited my answer with a bit more explanations)*

Comment: Thanks, i hope it wasn't too much trouble :D

Comment: It wasn't :-) Actually, that's kind of the funny questions about PHP and the stuff it does that's not always obvious ^^

Answer (score 3):

Because it isn't an array.  It's a string.

```
$test['hello'] = array();
$test['hello']['jerk'] = "JERK!"
```

You're trying to treat the string stored in `$test['hello']` as an array.  You're not going to be able to make `$test['hello']` hold both a string ("Hello There") and another array.

Comment: Thats right, $test['hello'] is declared as string initially in Mallow's code

Comment: Thank you, this helps me understand what I can do :D

Answer (score 3):

From https://www.php.net/language.types.string.

> Characters within strings may be
> accessed and modified by specifying
> the zero-based offset of the desired
> character after the string using
> square array brackets, as in
> $str[42]... Non-integer [indexes] are
> converted to integer... only the first
> character of an assigned string is
> used.

So, to answer your question. `$test['hello']` is a string, so the rules of indexing strings will apply. Therefore, `$test['hello']['jerk'] = "JERK!";` is equivalent to `$test['hello'][0] = "J";` because the intval of `'jerk'` is `0` and only the first character `"J"` of the assigned string `"JERK!"` will be used.

After, when echoing `$test['hello']`, you will be referring to the whole string, which now has its first character replaced by a `J`. Echoing `$test['hello']['jerk']` is again equivalent to echoing `$test['hello'][0]` because the intval of `'jerk'` is `0`, and by the rules of indexing strings, `$test['hello'][0]` will return the first character of `$test['hello']`.

In interpretation of what you meant to do, perhaps you wanted this.

```
$test['hello'] = "Hello There";
$test['jerk'] = "JERK!";
print_r($test); // array('hello' => "Hello There", 'jerk' => "JERK!")
```

Or, to have something multidimensional...

```
$test['message']['hello'] = "Hello There";
$test['message']['jerk'] = "JERK!";
print_r($test);
// array('message' => array('hello' => "Hello There", 'jerk' => "JERK!"))
```

Comment: D'oh, I was just about to submit an answer saying this.  Oh well, you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks, I love getting all these responses, it's my first time using stack overflow and I can't keep up with all the replies haha, this is wonderful!

Comment: actually I was trying to assign different values to aspects of a form variable so I set $formvalue['company']=$_POST['company'] and I wanted to reduce the amount of arguments I sent to a function so I thought I could do $formvalue['company']['errormessage'] and $formvalue['company']['elementname']='company'... I guess I should just make the post value = $formvalue['company']['value']

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to declare `$test['hello']` as two things: a string and an array. It can only be one or the other.

Answer (score 1):

It is worth pointing out that what is happening in the code example given.

A string can be accessed like an index-based array. When you attempt to set the second level of the "array" what it is actually doing is this (since the first level is a string):

```
$array['levelOne'] = 'Hello.';
$array['levelOne'][(int)'jerk'];
```

Basically this gives (or sets) the first character of the string since 'jerk' cast as an integer is 0. If your string could have cast to a different integer then it would have returned (or set) a different character of the string.